# Compare object without deep with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I compare two object with lodash without deep property??
In this case

```
var a = { a: 1 }
var b = { a: "1" }
```

I would like to be the same but with `isEqual` not work.

Comment: That's because these objects are not equal. You could probably use `_.isEqualWith` instead.

Comment: I would avoid using JavaScript's type casting as a feature. You will get very unexpected results. Instead, make both objects use the same types.